# h1-h6 tags: would I be penalised by Google for SEO for making content smaller than browser default?

Tags: seo

There are several reasons to use h1-h6 tags:

- Creates a hierarchy of title sizes from h1 (main title) downwards
- Provides a standardised size for titles
- Improves SEO

But if I change the size of an h1-6 tag's content from its default, will I be SEO-penalised by Google?

I have searched for an answer but cannot find one.

Comment: See [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/is-heading-h1-h2-h3-font-size-relevant-for-seo) related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Penalized for changing the font size?  No.   As long as you don't change the font size to zero or otherwise make it illegible to users Google won't penalize your site.

However you say you are using headings in part because they "improve SEO."  That isn't true anymore.  Google now renders pages and can tell how big and prominent text is on the page as it is rendered.   Google no longer gives weight to text that is in `h1` tags, it gives extra weight to text that is large and at the top of the page when it is rendered.  It doesn't matter if you use an `h1` tag to put that big prominent text there or whether you put it in a div with CSS rules.

So making your font sizes on your heading smaller won't get your site "penalized," but it may slightly reduce the amount of weight that Google places on the keywords that you use in those headings.